# Find $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'(t)$. Let $S : z = x^2+ y^2$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced metric and let $\gamma(t)$ be

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S : z = x^2+ y^2$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced metric and let $\gamma(t)$ be a curve on $S$ given by $\gamma(t) = (t, t, 2t^2)$. For the arc length s$(t) = \int_0^t|\gamma'(r)|dr$ , let $t = t(s)$ denote its inverse function.

Find $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'(t)$.

I know that the normal unit vector is $n={\nabla_g\over ||\nabla_g||}={<2x,2y,-z>\over \sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+z^2}}$ where $g(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2-z)=0$

Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the coordinate formula for $\nabla_X Y$ (in terms of Christoffel symbols) available? Alternatively, you can solve this without computation using the fact that the surface is symmetric about the plane $\{x = y\}$ containing the image the $\gamma$.

Comment: I don't have that. Interesting. How can I use the fact that it is symmetric?

Comment: Since $(S, g)$ is symmetric about that plane, $\nabla_{\gamma'} \gamma'$ must be, too, but that just means that it's contained in the plane. This plane intersects transversely the tangent line plane to $S$ and so must be contained in their line of intersection.